# Excel - Conditional Formatting - how to create 3 color scale based on values in each of the columns? Column by column not array

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

i have searched this for quite a bit of time but couldn't find the answer.

I have over hundreds of data, in columns and I want to create 3 color scale based on values in each columns individually (not across all the columns if I just highlight and create 3 color scale in one go).

The only method I knew is to create one column conditional formatting then format painter to each other columns one by one but this looks stupid and very time consuming. Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuirN.png)
this first image is the color scale created across some of the columns together. So some columns will be missing some green colors (for max values)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5uTj.png)

this second image is what i want, 3 color scale created in each column one by one.

Have searched everywhere and tried some method for using formulas in conditioning formatting but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Conditional formatting has trafic lights or bands, tried those?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean?